# Word that represents your truest desires

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for a word to describe the *desires of your heart*, in other words, what you are constantly thinking, or what worries you.  Usually things you would only confide with very close friends.

Comment: If we all spoke Old English, I would recommend *breosthord* (breast-hoard), which roughly means 'the great treasure of thoughts and feelings which we keep safe within our chests, ready to be shared with those willing and worthy'. Yes, I've taken poetic licence in that definition, but the word deserves it.

Answer (score 2):

*[Love](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/love)* captures one end of *true desire*:

> 3 [COUNT NOUN]
>   A person or thing that one loves:
>
> ODO

As the [quote](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/383261-music-is-the-love-of-my-life-it-s-a-total) from Miley Cyrus confirms:

> Music is the love of my life. It’s a total escape from reality. Music
>   transports you to another place, someplace unexpected and meaningful.
>
> *Miles to Go, retrieved from goodreads.com*

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=love&allowed_in_frame=0) shows that *love* is rooted in *desire*:

> Old English lufu "love, affection, friendliness,"
>   from Proto-Germanic
>   *lubo
>   (cognates: Old High German liubi "joy," German Liebe "love;" Old Norse, Old Frisian, Dutch lof; German Lob "praise;" Old Saxon liof,
>   Old Frisian liaf, Dutch lief, Old High German liob, German lieb,
>   Gothic liufs "dear, beloved").
>
> The Germanic words are from PIE ***leubh***- "***to care, desire, love***"
>   (cognates: Latin lubet, later libet "pleases;" Sanskrit lubhyati
>   "desires;" Old Church Slavonic l'ubu "dear, beloved;" Lithuanian
>   liaupse "song of praise").

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people to know about these desires (especially if they *worry* you), that might well be because you're ashamed of and tormented by them. In which case they're your...

> [**demons**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demon)
>    *a persistently tormenting person, force, or **passion***
>    *a person, habit, **obsession**, etc., thought of as evil, cruel, or persistently tormenting*

Answer (score 1):

For an adjective to use with ‘desires,’ I’d probably say “[innermost](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/innermost) desires,” but that’s still two words.

Our innermost desires often help us discover our “raison d’être” and develop a “sense of purpose” (all still multi-words), which in turn helps us determine our “[motivation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/motivation)” which is sometimes kept secret from everyone, even ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

One adjective that can describe the "desires of your heart" is *bona fide*. Your *bona fide* intentions or loves are those which​ are true and authentic.

(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bona%20fide)

Answer (score 0):

With respect to  *intimate thoughts or personal secrets* that one would talk about only with a trusted friend, I think  the term ***[confidence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/confidence)*** may fit:

> - that which is confided; ***a secret***: *a friend does not betray confidences.* (AHD)
> - ***something confided or entrusted***; secret

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Perhaps the word ' Confidante'  would be suiting as it  means according to Oxford.

> A person with whom one shares a secret or private matter, trusting them not to repeat it to others:
>   E.G "a close confidante of the princess."

Comment: Not looking for a word that describes to whom you reveal secrets.  But the secrets themselves.  I could use "secret", but I'm looking for a more specific term as my question implies.